# Adelic definition of "canonical divisor"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

For a function field over a curve $F/K$, some book define the canonical divisor as the divisor of a map $\omega:\mathscr{A}_{F}\rightarrow K$ (where $\mathscr{A}_{F}$ is the pre-adele, ie. adele but without completion at each prime) where $\omega$ is a continuous linear map that is trivial on the diagonal embedding of $F$.

In Tate's thesis, canonical divisor is hidden in the non-duality nature of measure of adele.

This suggests that there should be a definition of canonical divisor that use adele (instead of pre-adele like in previous case) that is more explicit (unlike the measure in the second case). But I can't find anything on this. Anyone know?